# Importing python library in two different own libaries

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have developed two different python libraries in my project and I use those two libraries in my build script. For Example,

In `lib1.py`, I `import pandas as pd`

and,

In `lib2.py`, I import pandas as same.

In my build script `run.py`, I import both `lib1` and `lib2`. So in this what python will do? How do I prevent importing python two time in my build script `run.py`?

Comment: You don't have to do anything: Python will safely and efficiently solve this behind the scenes for you. That is, Pandas will only be fully imported once, and there will be no clashes whatsoever.